# How to view network traffic in grails test-app? - perhaps RESTClient logging?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, logging

I use a grails project with only spock unit tests to make web calls to verify a set of web services.  It uses RESTClient to make the calls.

I've recently upgraded from Grails 2.0.0 to 2.3.4, and updated all the dependencies to the latest.

With the old environment running unit tests under GGTS, I used to see a trace of all network traffic - exceptionally useful for debugging problems.  Now this trace is missing, and instead I see the following sent to stderr at the start of each test:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (groovyx.net.http.RESTClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I've messed around a lot with log4j configuration in Setup.groovy, but it has no effect (indeed I understand that unit tests don't normally set up log4j).

How can I fix the latest groovyx.net.http.RESTClient to provide the network traces?

- Charles

Answer (score 0):

Ah - turns out the log4j config in Config.groovy doesn't work with tests from GGTS.  I created a file log4j.xml in source/groovy (i.e. on the class path) with this in it, and I can see the traces fine there.

But the Config.groovy configuration does work when I run the tests as `grails test-app`.  Go figure!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="  %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="groovyx.net.http">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>

    <!-- Use DEBUG to see basic request/response info;  
         Use TRACE to see headers for HttpURLClient. -->
    <category name="groovyx.net.http.HttpURLClient">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>
    <category name="groovyx.net.http.RESTClient">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.apache.http">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.apache.http.headers">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.apache.http.wire">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```